# Gridview.RowdataBound not working on first row

Tags: asp.net

I have this code for setting Background color in some cells in a Gridview, but i can't get it to work on the first row.

```
protected void GrdTask_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach(GridViewRow row in GrdTask.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[1].Text) == 0)
            {                   
                e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["Style"] = "background-color: #f20713";
            }               
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[1].Text) <= -3)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["Style"] = "background-color: #f4d942";
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[1].Text) <= -5)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["Style"] = "background-color: #28b779";
            }
        }          
    }
```

For all the rest of the rows it works fine. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping the rows in the RowDataBound event. you don't need to do that and will give incorrect results. The RowDataBound event is already called per row. Better use the DataRowView to get the correct value and color the cell based on that.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        int cellValue = Convert.ToInt32(row["ColumnName"]);

        if (cellValue == 0)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["style"] = "background-color: #f20713";
        }
        else if (cellValue <= -3)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["style"] = "background-color: #f4d942";
        }
        else if (cellValue <= -5)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["style"] = "background-color: #28b779";
        }
    }
}
```